# How to echo specific data from url

Tags: php, curl, get, file-get-contents

how to `echo/print` specific data from url using `file_get_content`.

im only know basic from it

here what i create

```
<?php
$homepage = ('http://www.aweb.org/dorama/1301193822/unnatural');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

for example here my content in real web

`<img src="">`

`<h2>title here</h2>`

`<h2>description here</h2>`

`<h2>casts here</h2>`

i want to print `img src`, `h2 title` and `h2 description`.

what I want to achieve is load a litle information from the url i insert, just like when we share link in facebook.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will help you: http://j-php.net/wiki/Jsoup-Extension

You can get data from specific elements. 
I was inspired by JSoup for Java, this is a PHP extension

Example Code:

```
use php\jsoup\Jsoup;

$doc = Jsoup::connect("http://www.piratefiles.org/dorama/1301193822/unnatural")->get();
$titles = $doc->select("h2");

foreach ($titles as $title) {
   echo "- {$element->text()}\n";
}
```

To list all h2's - you should properly extend it to your use, I cannot test it because I cannot access the site and dont understand the language on it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to use [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) library.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';   

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// finding img tags
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src ;

// finding h2 tags
foreach($html->find('h2') as $element)
       echo $element->plaintext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://htmlparsing.com/php.html

```
    <?php

# Use the Curl extension to query Google and get back a page of results
$url = "http://www.google.com";
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

# Create a DOM parser object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

# Parse the HTML from Google.
# The @ before the method call suppresses any warnings that
# loadHTML might throw because of invalid HTML in the page.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

# Iterate over all the <a> tags
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        # Show the <a href>
        echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";
}
?>
```